# Preventing User from accidentally quitting Shiny session

Tags: r, shiny, refresh

I'm new to Shiny and have no experience in web programming. I'm going to write a little shiny application which step-by-step receives new inputs from the user. 
Storing these values in a file would be inconvenient for the user, so this is not an option.
All I want and for which I haven't found a solution is a small window with two buttons popping up whenever the tab/window is to be closed or refreshed, asking the user whether he really wants to leave the application. This shall avoid data loss due to accidentally hitting a wrong button.

Are there such features or functions available or do you have any tips?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at the first example in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435890/disable-browsers-back-button-in-r-shiny-app. The topic there is about the 'back' button, but this works for closing and refreshing the browser window too.

Comment: That is very fine. Thank you two!